# Javascript matrix multiplication by scalar

Tags: javascript, object, matrix, scalar

I have an object called Cube. It is set up like this

```
//Cube object
    function Cube(vertices, color, scale) 
    {
        //this.vertices = vertices;
        this.setColor(color);
        this.setScale(vertices, 1);
    }
```

I commented out `//this.vertices = vertices;` because im not sure if I have to set vertices here or set them within `setScale()` function.
I want to set a scale on a matrix. The matrix is:

```
var verts = [
            // Front face
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

            // Back face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

            // Top face
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

            // Bottom face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Right face
             1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
             1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
             1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

            // Left face
            -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
            -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
        ];
```

The function i use to set the scale is like this:

```
Cube.prototype.setScale = function(vertices, scale) 
    {
        var length = vertices.length;
        for( var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            //alert("before "+ vertices[i]+ " i "+ i);
            vertices[i] *= scale; 
            //alert("after "+ vertices[i]);
        }
```

I think that by doing this the for loop should take the matrix length and start a for loop.
Within this for loop I will get the vertice at i and multiply it by the scale.
When I do it like this though the for loop will reiterate. I.e. when i hits 72 the loop does not stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I commented out `//this.vertices = vertices;` because im not sure if I have to set vertices here

You either need to set it there or at the end of the constructor. Your `setScale` function is nicely decoupled from where the `vertices` array is stored and I'd keep it that way. But you might consider renaming it `scaleVertices()` instead.

> When I do it like this though the for loop will reiterate. I.e. when i hits 72 the loop does not stop.

Really? That's odd. I must be missing something; the code looks correct.

Don't use `alert()`, by the way, it will make your life hell to debug anything. You're much better using `console.log()`.

Comment: I have implemented the name changes and uncommented the `this.vertices` this has fixed the vertices and resized them.